# ¿Cómo puedo redireccionar a una parte específica de mi página después de algún proceso en el controlador?

Tags: java, html, jsp

Quiero que despues de que mi codigo, ha hecho ciertos procedimientos me redireccione a un div en especifico de mi index lo he intentado de esta manera pero no haya la pagina:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp#contenedor3").forward(request,response);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma en que lo pude solucionar fue usando

> HttpSesion session=request.getSession();
>   session.setAttribute("NombreParametro","ValorDeParametro");
>   response.sendRedirect("index.jsp#contenedor1");

Answer (score 1):

La redireccion a determinada posicion solo puedes realizarla desde el lado del cliente.
Podrias usar librerias como ser

[jquery.scrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo)

Entonces no necesitas definir un ancla de html, sino que le indicas al id de cual div o control en tu página te quieres desplazar.

En el ejemplo veras como el div esta bien abajo despues de varios parrafos, pero el `$.scroolTo()` mueve el scroll a la posicion del div para dejarlo visible

```js
$(function(){
  
  $.scrollTo("#div1");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.scrollto/2.1.2/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>

<p>linea </p>
<p>linea</p>
<p>linea</p>
<p>linea </p>
<p>linea </p>
<p>linea </p>
<p>linea </p>
<p>linea </p>
<p>linea </p>
<p>linea </p>
<p>linea </p>
<p>linea </p>
<p>linea</p>
<p>linea </p>
<p>linea </p>
<p>linea </p>
<p>linea</p>
<p>linea </p>
<p>linea </p>
<p>linea </p>
<p>linea</p>
<p>linea </p>
<p>linea </p>
<p>linea </p>

<div id="div1"> contenido div </div>
```

Comment: En realidad, el problema puede corregirse si se utilizara redirect en lugar de forwarding.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que con el forward estoy enviando unos parametros que se deben de mostrar en el index.jsp, por eso no puedo utilizar el redirect

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, al utilizar esto

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp#contenedor3").forward(request,response);
```

Estás ejecutando un forward, no un redirect. Esto no te permitirá ubicarte en la posición que deseas. Si utilizas forward, tu mejor opción será hacer el forward a tu vista JSP directamente, en este caso index.jsp, y luego al cargar la página ejecutar un código JavaScript que te permita navegar al anchor. Puedes hacerlo de esta manera.

```
$(document).ready = () {
    window.location = '#contenedor3'; //asumiendo que tu anchor funciona
};
```

En vista que estás utilizando forward, puedes agregar un atributo en tu request para este caso particular, de manera que solo cuando se acceda a la página mediante el procesamiento de este request. Podrías tener algo así.

En tu controller:

```
request.setAttribute("anchor", "contenedor3");
request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp#contenedor3").forward(request,response);
```

En tu vista (jsp):

```
<c:if test="${anchor eq 'contenedor3'}">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready = () {
            window.location = '#contenedor3'; //asumiendo que tu anchor funciona
        };
    </script>
</c:if>
```

La otra opción, si es viable, es utilizar un redirect hacia tu página y anchor.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que al implementar esto, la ruta no se encuentra, esto es el fragmento de codigo                                                                                                switch(opcion){
            case 1:// AGREGAR REGISTROS
              if(DDepartamento.agregarRegistro()){
                    request.setAttribute("mensajeD", MensajeExitoD);
                }else{
                    request.setAttribute("mensajeD", MensajeErrorD);
                }
                request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);